# Винлокер на python

Tags: python

при запуске винлокера все работает отлично(то есть экран можно разблокировать с помощью пароля) а вот когда просто выключаешь компьютер и заново включаешь, то винлокер пытается запуститься автоматически через командную строку(т.к. пк был выключен через выдергивание шнура из розетки) , но не может

выдает такую ошибку(см. скрин)

запуск винлокера осуществляется из командной строки

как исправить это?(т.е. на данный момент получается, что просто выключением ПК можно его обойти)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте запустить от админа

Comment: @gil9red а что именно ? сам файл? или командную строку?

Comment: консоль от администратора

Comment: Консоль от админа. Либо переместите файл с C:/myFiles в папку юзера, тогда не придется от админа запускать

Comment: добавьте код пожалуйста